# What is the cardinality of the set of solutions for separable PDEs? (e.g. 1D heat conduction problem)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, partial-differential-equations

In my Intro to PDE class today, we discussed separable PDEs and their solutions using the 1D heat conduction problem as an example. As we worked through the example, the professor concluded that the solutions are of the form
$$u_{n}(x,t)=B_{n}sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}e^{-k(\frac{n\pi}{L})^{2}t}$$
where $x$, $t$ are the variables for position and time, $L$ is the upper boundary and $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$, as well as any linear combination of these by the superposition principle.

This made me think about something I had learned in my Advanced Analysis class the day before, that the power set of the natural numbers has a bijection with the reals, making its cardinality uncountable infinite. If we assume that the infinite sum of solutions to the heat conduction problem converges, could we not represent all solutions as a set of natural numbers, i.e. $u(x,t)=B_{2}sin\frac{2\pi x}{L}e^{-k(\frac{2\pi}{L})^{2}t}+B_{5}sin\frac{5\pi x}{L}e^{-k(\frac{5\pi}{L})^{2}t}$ as {$2, 5$} and so on? Then, if we defined the empty set as the trivial solution $u(x, t)=0$, could we define the set of solutions to this problem as the power set of the naturals, making it an uncountably infinite set?

Sorry in advance for not rigorously formalizing my argument, this was just an interesting possibility that crossed my mind and I wanted to know if there were any flaws in my thought process.

EDIT: As StinkingBishop has pointed out, solutions to the heat problem can also be of the form $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}e^{-k(\frac{n\pi}{L})^{2}t}$$
I assume these would represent countably infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and thus still contribute to the power set, but I am open to correction if wrong.

EDIT 2: As a result of the boundary condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$, $B_n$ is uniquely determined by $n$ and $f(x)$ with the function $B_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}f(x)dx$, so there isn't infinite possible selections of $B_n$ just infinite selections and combinations of $n\in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Um... it is a lot more complicated. The point is that even some *infinite* sums of the form $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_{n}sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}e^{-k(\frac{n\pi}{L})^{2}t}$ are solutions of your PDE, where $B_n$'s are all real coefficients that you can choose quite freely (certainly at least as long as the sum on the RHS converges absolutely). So there are "a lot more" ways to pick the solution than you think.

Comment: Having said that, the $B_n$ is really a map of $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ i.e. belongs to $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ so its cardinality comes out the same as $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\times\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$, i.e. the same as the number of subsets of $\mathbb N$. I don't know if this has any deeper significance.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks for your response. When I wrote "any linear combination" I meant to imply those linear combinations that could also be represented as infinite sums, but I think you are right to point out that I should be more clear. Regarding their place in the power set, I would assume they would simply be countably infinite subsets of the natural numbers and therefore not outside the scope of the power set. I don't think they interfere with my argument meaningfully, but I am open to correction.

Comment: I am saying that different values of $B_n$ give you different solutions, i.e. you shouldn't just vary the *set* of $n$'s for which the terms $B_n\sin(\cdots)e^{(\cdots)}$ appear, but you also need to vary the coefficients $B_n$ themselves.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Right, I should've clarified the initial conditions. One of them is $u(x,0)=f(x)$. As a result of this, $B_n$ is uniquely determined by $f(x)$ and $n$ in the function $B_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}f(x)dx$ for $n=1, 2, 3, ...$ which comes from using our equation when $t=0$ as a Fourier series to approximate f(x) and solving for $B_n$. In total, you could represent the solutions as $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}sin\frac{2n\pi x}{L^{2}}e^{-k(\frac{n\pi}{L})^{2}t}\int_{0}^{L}sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}f(x)dx$.

Comment: Ah, yes, but then ... the cardinality of your set of solutions is precisely $1$. (It is unique.)

Comment: For the infinite sum solution, yes. But that's just one of many valid solutions. There's still all the solutions $u_{n}(x,t)=B_{n}sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}e^{-k(\frac{n\pi}{L})^{2}t}$ for all $n=1, 2, 3, ...$ as well as any finite linear combination of these solutions.

Comment: You must be more precise (in your question) what exactly you want to be counted. Then we can see its cardinality and whether putting into $1-1$ correspondence to $2^{\mathbb N}$ makes sense. You realise that, if the initial condition is given, then there is a single solution, and if you look across all the initial conditions, then $B_n$ can all vary across the whole $\mathbb R$ (although not quite independently, to ensure convergence). It seems to me that you somehow implicitly assume that each $B_n$ is either $1$ or $0$ - but this is plainly wrong.

Comment: I don't really see how I could be more clear, and it seems you keep misunderstanding me. I'm not "assuming" $B_n$ is either $1$ or $0$, I'm saying that the infinite sum solution is not the only valid solution. Our $u_n(x,t)$ solutions form an infinite sequence of separated solutions that are also valid solutions to the 1D heat conduction problem, as well as any finite linear combination of these solutions.

Comment: What's being counted, therefore, is all of the separated solutions (all sets in the power set with one entry), all finite linear combinations of these (all finite sets in the power set with more than one entry), the infinite sum solution ($\mathbb{N}$, as power sets contain the set itself), and the trivial solution $u(x,t)=0$ (the empty set). This would mean we could represent the solutions of the PDE as the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, unless I've missed something.

Comment: Ah, ok. So you have calculated the function $u=\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n u_n$ and you want to calculate the cardinality of the set of the solutions $\sum_{n\in X}B_n u_n$ where $X\subseteq\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ is a subset of the full set of indices $\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$. Sure, although this looks like an odd choice. Also, depending on $f$, some/most/maybe all of $B_n$'s may be zero so you may be double-counting.